# How can I make a Google Map marker redirect to a URL?

Tags: javascript, django, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, django-templates

Here is my html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <style>
        /* Set the size of the div element that contains the map */
        #map {
            height: 700px; /* The height is 400 pixels */
            width: 100%; /* The width is the width of the web page */
        }
    </style>
    <!--The div element for the map --> flavor

    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        // Initialize and add the map
        function initMap() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(
                document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: {'lat': 42.6803769, 'lng': -89.03211}});
            {% for Listing in posts %}
                new google.maps.Marker({position: {'lat': {{ Listing.lat }}, 'lng': {{ Listing.lng }}}, map: map});
            {% endfor %}
        }
    </script>
    <!--Load the API from the specified URL
    * The async attribute allows the browser to render the page while the API loads
    * The key parameter will contain your own API key (which is not needed for this tutorial)
    * The callback parameter executes the initMap() function
    -->
    <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=***&callback=initMap">
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

I need to make the line:

```
new google.maps.Marker({position: {'lat': {{ Listing.lat }}, 'lng': {{ Listing.lng }}}, map: map});
```

redirect to `/preview/{{ Listing.pk }}` when clicked.

How can I make my marker a clickable link? I've looked at some examples online and the code seems vastly different from mine. Probably because I'm using the Google Maps example code along with some weird Django templating things. Is there a way I can just but my marker inside an  tag and put my URL in "href="?

Comment: I edited out your API key, but as it's still visible in the edit history, you might want to invalidate that key and get a new one, if it's not restricted to you domain(s) anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really believe that you didn't find anything, I'm quite positive there's something about that in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). Anyway, it should be as easy as this:

```js
var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {
    'lat': {
      {
        Listing.lat
      }
    },
    'lng': {
      {
        Listing.lng
      }
    }
  },
  map: map,
  url: '/preview/{{ Listing.pk }}'
});
google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'click', function() {
  window.location.href = this.url;
});
```

You define a custom `url` property on the marker, then register a `click` event that changes the current URL to `this.url` (the marker's `url` property you defined above).

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the reference is overwritten over and over again, the actual marker should still be there and have a working click event. Let me know if not (can't try it out myself right now) and I'll update the code to use an index in the variable name.